# sudo yum install postfix mysql-libs error

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta, yum

I am trying to install postfix through yum:

```
sudo yum install postfix
```

After I run the code below I get the following error:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.6.6-6.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: mysql-libs
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
sendmail-cf-8.14.4-8.el6.noarch has missing requires of sendmail = ('0', '8.14.4', '8.el6')
```

I then ran it with '--skip-broken', but then postfix did not work. How can i resolve this error and properly install postfix?

Answer (score 2):

the answer can be found here: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=47583 . I have to update the yum.config file and remove mysql.