# How to install GitLab on CentOS 6 running WHM?

Tags: gitlab, centos6, postfix-mta

I am trying to install [GitLab](http://gitlab.com/) on my dedicated server with no luck.

Server info:

- CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 standard
- WHM 11.52.1 (build 2)

I tried [this](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos6) guide, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * updates: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs for package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: mysql-libs
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

When I run the following command:

> `sudo yum install postfix`

I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                  |  12 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * epel: mirrors.mit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.netelligent.ca
base                                                                                                                           | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                           | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                | 5.8 MB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                         | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                        | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                             | 2.6 MB     00:00     
virtualbox/signature                                                                                                           |  198 B     00:00     
virtualbox/signature                                                                                                           |  951 B     00:00 ... 
No package mysql-libs available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

When I run the following command:

> `sudo yum install mysql-libs`

Comment: Strange: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1150Docs/11.50+Release+Notes includes The upgrade to cPanel & WHM version 11.50.0.11 or later forcibly removes the following RPMs due to a conflict with the Exim RPM: postfix. postfix is not listed in https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/1150Docs/Third-Party+Software.

Comment: And why can't you run `sudo yum install mysql-libs` before trying to install postfix ?

Comment: @jeanMarcAssin check the updated question

Comment: I think you may need to remove exim before installing postfix. I'm not sure an EL system allows more than one MTA, but I do know it requires at least one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I eventually did was skip the installation of **postfix**. I skipped it like so:

```
sudo yum install --skip-broken curl openssh-server openssh-clients postfix cronie
```

Then I edited the **gitlab.rb** config file using something like nano:

```
nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and changed the **external_url'** and added to it a random unused port number:

```
external_url 'http://example.com:8443/'
```

then run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

for the change to take effect.

Voila it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a common problem with CentOS. Similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458244/sudo-yum-install-postfix-mysql-libs-error) on fixing the `yum install postfix` and missing `mysql-libs`.

NOTE: Since I can't comment I will provide this as an answer and update based on any comments.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the Bitnami one-click install GitLab. It's very easy to install GitLab.

More info :  https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab

and Wiki is : https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_GitLab#How_to_change_the_default_address_for_GitLab.3f